# DB script for changing the model of mongoDB collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

My application is using **mongoDB** for data persistence and this application is already deployed on production as well and working fine.

Now, there is a client requirement to change the certain section of a collection which is already been used and having a million records in prod.

Collection name is `changeRecord`, earlier it was having an embedded section as per below snapshot :

[image]

Now, as per new requirement I need to change the `extSystem` **single embedded system** into **embedded array** and field name from `extCRid` to `extId` as per below snapshot :

[image]

Here as we can see single embedded system has been changed to embedded array and a field name is also changed.
I need to perform this activity, but I'm not a DB expert. I'm using **mongoDB** in my application for last 1 year but it's from java side using spring-boot and spring-mongo.

Please help me to write a DB script for this, as there is already lots of records are there in prod environment, therefore I can't take risk to fail as well.
These changes need to be done from DB side only, not from application side.

I tried writing the below script for field name change but not getting through for changing into array Type. :

```
db.changerecord.update({"extSystem":{"$exists":true}}, {$rename:{"extSystem.extCRid":"extSystem.extId"}}, false, true);
```

Comment: Any suggestions, please..!!

Comment: @NeilLunn - I didn't find my query resolution in the link you shared. There is no reference in that link that how we can change it from single embedded system to embedded array.

Comment: Interesting. Because there's a pretty prominent example using `.aggregate()` and `$out`. And all you really need do it wrap your current value in an array. Perhaps reading the many answers there and linked documentation from them might find a better resolution for you.